# Shortcut for null operator check and assignment in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

What is the shortcut for the following in coffeescript

```
if x then x += 1 else x = 0
```

Comment: You can't really get smaller than `x=if x then x+1else 0` - the same in pure JS would be `var x=x?x+1:0`.

Comment: It is actually if x then x += 1 else x = 1

Answer (score 1):

since `x += 1 if x` would leave `x` as whatever falsey value it was (which could be null or undefined or false), if you want to set `x` to 0, you'll need to be more specific.

in coffeescript, an if/else statement is an expression, so you can just assign it that way:

```
x = if x then x + 1 else 0
```

This is the equivalent of the javascript ternary expression:

```
x = x ? x + 1 : 0
```

Answer (score 0):

When I read the title of your question, I thought you may be looking for `x ?= 1`, which compiles to `x != null ? x : x = 1;`. But this is not what you want.